# Compilation error when running ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net

Getting this compile error when I debug the ASP.NET project. How do I add the reference properly?

> `Compilation Error`
>
> `Description: An error occurred during
>   the compilation of a resource required
>   to service this request. Please review
>   the following specific error details
>   and modify your source code
>   appropriately.`
>
> `Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The
>   type or namespace name 'BasePage'
>   could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)`
>
> `Source Error:`
>
> `Line 8:  namespace DisplayPage.UI
>   Line 9:  { Line 10:     public partial
>   class _Default : BasePage Line 11:
>
>   { Line 12:         protected void
>   Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`

I am using .NET 3.5 and vs 2008

Comment: Is BasePage a class that you define?

Comment: I always find when the following is displayed it's not lying...
`are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what namespace is BasePage in?
I'm not quite sure how to make ASP.NET find classes from source files in the regular directory. I usually circumvent this problem by moving classes I want to access in that fashion into App_Code. Make sure you give it a namespace and import it.